# Is it possible to backup android app favorites

Tags: applications, backup

I've a Samsung Galaxy Note 4. I would like to flash a new Firmware but I've installed many apps.

Is there any app which can help me to keep my apps favorites and settings so that I can recover all the settings et favorites after reinstall?

Comment: Is your device rooted?

Comment: Non,it isn't rooted